# Отследить вывод в консоль

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Есть ли способ отследить любой вывод в консоль `console.log, console.warn, console.error` у фрейма или окна созданого основным процессом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно переопределить объект консоли, например:

```
(function(){
    // Сохраняем ссылку на оригинальный объект консоли
    var _privateLog = console.log;
    // Переопределяем метод console.log своей функцией
    console.log = function (message) {
        // Здесь производятся необходимые действия
        // alert("Our Custom Log Says: " + message);

        /**
          Следующая строка необходима, если нужно сохранить функционал оригинальной консоли
         */
        _privateLog.apply(console, arguments);
    };
})();
```

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/104/how-to-override-the-console-methods-in-javascript